# Programming in the Calculus of Inductive Constructions with Coq

Tags: coq, dependent-type, theorem-proving

Sometimes I want to write programs close to bare-bone CIC (Calculus of Inductive Constructions) to get a better grasp of the internal workings.
I then need to customize some settings to change the default behavior of the Coq environment, such as `Set Printing Implicit`.

Are there more that I can do?

Comment: To put it another way, how to disable all the Coq extensions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want no syntactic sugar *at all* you should do `Set Printing All`.

Answer (score 1):

You can launch coq with the `-noinit` option, that will avoid loading the Prelude, so as long as you don't use notations, you are pretty close to the bare CIC calculus, but as of today there is not way to disable type-inference.